# How should I handle all my errors in one place?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know how I should handle my errors in one place using node.js

This is how I did:

First I create loggers/errors.js

And inside I have this object:

```
var Errors = {
 bad_request: 'Some error related with bad request'
};
```

Than, in other files I just require this file, and when some statement or some error can occur, i just call:

```
var Errors = require('../loggers/errors');

if (something here) {
 console.log(Errors.bad_request);
}
```

I would like to know if this is a good approach, if I am doing right, or if there is a module that already does what I want, but with extra features.

Comment: I see no issue with it, especially if it works.

Comment: You can emit events and bind them in a central place.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    BadRequest: 'Request was bad',
    Timeout: 'Server timed out'
}
```

And require it in the main file

```
var Error = require ('../loggers/errors.js');

if(statement) {
    console.log (Error.BadRequest );
}
```

You need to declare module.exports or it won't be able to be required.